# unable to execute php files in google cloud service

Tags: php5, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

[Here is my site link](https://adb-madinenivishwateja.appspot.com) and when i try to login then in network the response i get is the whole login.php code instead of the response after executing the php file. My app.yaml file is correct i have already double check it. My php files unable to execute in google cloud services.
Here is my app.yaml code

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico
- url: /css
  static_dir: css
- url: /images
  static_dir: images
- url: /fonts
  static_dir: fonts
- url: /utils
  static_dir: utils
- url: /js
  static_dir: js  
- url: /index.html
  script: /index.html
- url: /signup.html
  script: /signup.html
- url: /.*
  script: index.html 
- url: /utils/login.php
  script: /utils/login.php
- url: /js/login.js
  script: /js/login.js
- url: /js/script.js
  script: /js/script.js
- url: /js/jquery.min
  script: /js/jquery.min
- url: /js/bootstrap.min
  script: /js/bootstrap.min
- url: .*
  script: main.php
```

and here is my login.php code

```
<?php


require 'dblinker.php';

function login(){
    try {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        // login function
        $handle=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`= :username AND `password`= :password");
        $handle->bindParam('username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $handle->bindParam('password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $handle->execute();
        if($handle->rowCount() == 1){
            $result=$handle->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $_SESSION["username"] = $result['username'];
            $_SESSION["role_id"] = $result['role_id'];
            echo "success";
        }else{
            echo "fail";
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo "F";
    }
}
session_start();
echo login();

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that it's a LAMP stack environment that you are in.

You need to install the related dependencies:

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt php-mysql php php-gd php-pear php-curl
```

Comment: Hi
i am not using linux i am using app service .. there you can't install like linux so i don't understand what you mean to say ?

Comment: Ok, I see. But may you format the code a little bit before posting ?

Answer (score 1):

First please check phpinfo page working or not? Try with php-info.php using below code

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Please refer docs for [PHP Runtime Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/runtime) and [app.yaml Reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps modifying your app.yaml a little bit. For the last part:

```
 - url: .* 
   script: main.php
```

You are missing a forward slash. It should be:

```
- url: /.* 
  script: main.php
```

Comment: I change it too but still the same issue. Unable to execute the php files.

Comment: Are you deploying it using the PHP app engine ?  Try the "Hello World" template first to see if it work.